# How to install a .NET Windows Forms application on all the machines on the network?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, windows-installer, setup-deployment

I have created a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application in .NET 4.0. Now there are about 20 client machines where the application has to be reinstalled every time there is a build change.

Is there a way I can push the application to all the machines in the client network in a single go?

Comment: It depends whether the "server" has permission to view all of the machines? You could do something as simple as just copy the update EXE to all of the computers so \\pc1, \\pc2 etc. What network is this on, corporate, local group?

Comment: Did you create a click-once application ? Or a regular setup ?

Comment: T Fabre posted a response as I was typing up my answer.  Forgot to mention, ClickOnce is integrated within Visual Studio, and has been since 2003.  It's really easy to use, but I recommend a test build, publish and client install a time or two before you officially release.  If you have questions, ask them on this site.  There are a few gurus I know who are keen to answer ClickOnce questions.

Comment: I created a regular setup...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.140).aspx) is your friend.

In short, ClickOnce allows you to publish an application to a server and users can browse to an associated installation website and install your software.

If your ClickOnce settings are set properly, each time the user launches the application, the application will check for an update on the server, download it if it exists and update then application.

It's worth noting that with each update, the entire application is re-installed.  This can save you a ton of headaches but if your application is large, it could be a nightmare for your users if you update the system frequently.  Hit the link provided above for all of Microsoft's information regarding this deployment mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

You can have your sysadmin create a Group Policy to do this.

Comment: This is the easiest method for doing this, assuming that your application is just an executable and does not require an installer.

Comment: Installations can be done via GPO as well.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake